# Setting node ID sequence to a particular higher value for future created records

Tags: 8, migrations

We have an organic groups based portal in D7 where many blood banks add records. We recently initiated Drupal 8 migration and are close to completion. However, we would want to add selective blood banks first to the new D8 portal, have it tested before we ask all the other blood banks to use the new portal.

Is it possible to set a higher NID value when new records are created by new users? Migration data for remaining customers can happen seamlessly as their NID values will be lower.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem of migration data having higher nid values? Nids have no meaning, part of a unique identifier. I think you should just create the blood banks to test the site and later import data.

Comment: I just want to agree and strengthen the point of sanzante... no one cares about high or low ids but it messes up many things when do something wrong with that topic.

Comment: @sanzante: My assumption was that a D7 portal record to be migrated will fail if the D8 portal already has another record with the same node ID.  Please confirm that migration will work irrespective of node ids conflict. If so, then there is no need for higher sequence number for node ids.

Comment: Usually, when you migrate content node IDs are regenerated, so you don't have to take care of that. Of course, if you code a custom migrate process you may keep the node IDs (or any other entity ID) but this is discouraged. Standard migrations don't keep node IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set the `nid` to a higher value in your D8 instance, then continue to migrate D7 nodes under that.

Something like the following to set the `auto_increment` value.

```
// Set the next auto increment field value on the table
$result = db_query('ALTER TABLE {' . $connection->escapeTable($table) . '} AUTO_INCREMENT = ' . (int)$auto_increment);
```

e.g for `node` and `node_revision`

```
// Set the next auto increment field value on the node tables
$result = db_query('ALTER TABLE {node} AUTO_INCREMENT = 8000000');
$result = db_query('ALTER TABLE {node_revision} AUTO_INCREMENT = 8000000');
```

Comment: Thanks. My query has been resolved by @sazante's comment. Is altering the two tables: node and node_revision sufficient in D8 for changing auto-increment values for newly created node ids?

Comment: Yes, that's enough for the node entity type. I've used that technique to keep the same node ids between D7 and D8 after migration.